# Error importing pandas on Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, pandas, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3

I am trying to work with pandas on the Raspberry Pi, but it seems that Python is not recognizing that I have the module installed and is saying that pandas does not exist, despite the fact that I have used:

```
pip install pandas
```

as well as:

```
sudo apt-get install python-pandas
```

I would appreciate it if someone could let me know what is causing this strange error.

UPDATE:

Here is the error:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/pi/Desktop/NeuralNetwork.py", line 4, in <module>
    import pandas as pd
ImportError: No module named 'pandas'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Python 2.7.13 and and 3.5.3 are both installed](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=191667) by default on Raspberry Pi.

This might cause some issues if you install Pandas on the version that you aren't supposed to. Like you might be using another python version for production. For example I use python 3.6 on my projects and I currently have all 2.7, 3.5 and 3.6 installed at the same time.

You should check which python interpreter pip is linked to, since it might be installing you pandas on your Python 2 installation.

Start by trying pip3 instead of pip

In my case I also installed python3.6 so I had to use pip3.6

Comment: how do I check which python interpreter pip is linked to?

Comment: first of all, do you know which version are you using to run your final code?

Comment: yup python 3.5.3 I believe

Comment: definitiely above python 3

Comment: pip is usually linked to python 2 by default, try using pip3 to install pandas and see if the import works

Comment: I assume it worked now since you haven't said anything (?)

Comment: Oh yeah sorry it worked. I marked your answer as correct and have moved on to another problem.